# Pattern is stuck in a continuous loop

Tags: java

I am having some issues with getting my pattern to print correctly. If I comment out pattern 2 pattern 1 prints correctly. If I comment out pattern 1 pattern 2 prints correctly. Can someone point out why I can't get this to print like I want. It should print a star pattern one way and then the opposite way with one System.out.print("*"); command System.out.println();

```
   public class Pattern {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
         int a;
         int b;

         //pattern 1
         for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
           for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)

             //pattern2
             for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++){
               for (b = 1; b <= 11 - a; b++)    
                 System.out.print("*");
               System.out.println();
             }
        }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you comment out a pattern, you make that code "invisible" to the compiler. You're saying, "Skip me! I'm unimportant."

By the way, Java doesn't look for indentations. It does, however, look for the number of statements under the argument (**when there are no brackets present**). You can nest an argument inside another argument like the code below:

```
for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
    for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)
         for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
             for (b = 1; b <= 11 - a; b++)
```

**Note, the code above is not the answer to your pattern.** It is meant to explain to you how for statements **without brackets** work to help you solve the problem on your own :). In the case of using patterns, I would recommend consistently using brackets to nest your statements (especially since you are going to need print statements within your for loops). Note, in the code above, each for statement has only **one** statement below it. That's why this would work without brackets. If you add a print statement like this:

```
for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
    for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)
         System.out.print("*")//the next line will not be nested inside the above for loops
         for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
             for (b = 1; b <= 11 - a; b++)
```

The last two for loops will not be nested within the second for loop since the compiler will only allow one statement underneath a for loop without brackets. As you can see, not using brackets can get pretty confusing.

With your particular code, your issue lies with how it is nested (**using brackets**):

//For Loop #1
`for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++)`

//For Loop #2
`{for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)`// note there is no closed bracket here

//For Loop #3
`for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++){`

//For Loop #4
`for (b = 1; b <= 11 - a; b++)`// note there is no closed bracket here

```
 System.out.print("*");
 System.out.println();} } } }` //source of your problem
```

By placing your closed brackets( **}** ) in that location (where I wrote source of your problem), you are nesting Loop #4 , Loop #3, and Loop #2 **within** Loop #1. That's why your patterns change when you comment out your code.

Consider moving your brackets. Note that if you need to separate pattern one and pattern two, you will also need to have print statements for each pattern.

Often with pattern questions, you need to think of your for statements as rows and columns. Hint, a lot of pattern questions want you to consider your outer for loop as a row and your inner for loop as a column.

Example:

```
for(int a = 0; a<=3; a++)//rows
{
      for(int b = 0; b<=a; b++)//columns
      {
           System.out.print("*");//use print() so that the asterisks print on the same line
      }

      System.out.println();//This will create your rows(separates each iteration with a new line)
}
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
```

Something like this should get you started:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{

    int a;
    int b;

    //pattern 1
    for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
    {
        for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");//this creates each column

        }
        System.out.println();/*
                              * this marks the end of a row and brings the
                              * asterisks down to the next line
                              */
    }

    //pattern2
    for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++)
    {
        for (b = 1; b <= 11 - a; b++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");//this creates each column

        }
        System.out.println();/*
                              * this marks the end of a row and brings the
                              * asterisks down to the next line
                              */
    }
}
```

Also, refer to the Java style guide to clean up your code :). http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: this does not work at all. Maybe I'm closing it the wrong way for                  (b = 1; b <= 11 - a; b++);} It only prints 1 star. Also what code am I commenting out??

Comment: You only have one print statement located at the bottom of your code. It's likely that you are removing that print statement from the for loop when you are closing out the bracket. Isolate the patterns and use a separate print statement for each pattern. Make sense?

Comment: Made some edits to my response to help clarify my suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Always use correct indentation!
If you do, you will see that your code is

```
for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
    for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)
        for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++){
            for (b = 1; b <= 11 - a; b++)  
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

This is not what you want, especially because you overwrite you variables in the for loops. You want this:

```
    // pattern 1
    for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
        for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }
    // pattern2
    for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
        for (b = 1; b <= 11 - a; b++)
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

---

In case you are allowed to use only one print statement, here are two ways to achieve the desired output. These ways are a little tricky because that is not the intuitive way of writing a for loop.

**Loop 1**

In this example, you increase a until you reach the last line. Then you decrease it again (counting backwards). Important: `a <= 10 && a > 0`

```
    int counter = 1;
    for (a = 1; a <= 10 && a > 0; a += counter) {
        for (b = 1; b <= a; b++) {
            if (b == 10)
                counter = -1;
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**Loop 2**
Here, the outer loop has the double number of steps and you make the number of stars printed dependent on the line you currently are in.

```
    for (a = 1; a <= 20; a++) {
        for (b = 1; b <= -Math.abs(a-10)+10; b++) {

            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: I can only use one System.out.print("*"); command System.out.println();                I need to interupt the first loop with an if statement I presume but even if I throw in the if statement that I am playing with now it just continually loops

Comment: @jake Added two code samples that uns only one print command with a star.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //pattern 1
    for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
        for (b = 1; b <= a; b++)


            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }
    //pattern2
    for (a = 1; a <= 10; a++) {
        for (b = 1; b <= 10 - a; b++)

            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: I can only use one System.out.print("*"); command System.out.println();

Comment: why can't you use more than one? @jake